# what is the difference between :.! and :r!?

Tags: vim

reading up on some vim tips, I came across `:r!{command}` and `:.!{command}`, both of which take the output of the shell `<command>` and put it in the current buffer.
I imagine the '`r`' to stand for 'read', but how am I to 'translate' the dot in the command above?

And: do they have the exact same function?

Thanks a lot for your insights!

Guba

Comment: Perhaps this should go to superuser, since it's a user question not programming? [@Guba, don't worry about moving it, it'll happen automatically if need be. The beta password is at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/, don't forget to link your account, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/ ]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The dot is a region, referring to the current line. The `!` then takes this region and pipes it through the command.

So, for example, if you do:

```
:.!rev
```

You'll reverse the order of characters in the current line.

Of course, if you use a command that ignores its input, you'll just replace the current line with whatever the output is.

`:r!`, on the other hand, inserts the output after the current line, without removing the current line's text.

Comment: Brilliant! Cheers for the quick and precise reply!

Comment: :.r! not work for me. It don't takes line and pipes this to command.

Comment: lionbest, please note that no mention was made of :.r! . It's either :.!{command} or :r!{command}.